# Links to .woff and .tff does not work after minification

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am budndling all my CSS using style bundles and them using Style render.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/assets")
                    .Include(
                             "~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "~/assets/css/one.style.css",
                             "~/assets/css/footers/footer-v7.css"
                     ));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/plugin")
                                        .Include("~/assets/plugins/animate.css",
                                                    "~/assets/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css",
                                                    "~/assets/plugins/pace/pace-flash.css",
                                                    "~/assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css",
                                                    "~/assets/plugins/cube-portfolio/cubeportfolio/css/cubeportfolio.min.css",
                                                    "~/assets/plugins/cube-portfolio/cubeportfolio/custom/custom-cubeportfolio.css",
                                                    "~/assets/plugins/login-signup-modal-window/css/style.css",
                                                    "~/assets/css/plugins/style-switcher.css",
                                                    //Not plugins , but included for page load sequence
                                                    "~/assets/css/theme-skins/one.dark.css",
                                                    "~/assets/css/custom.css"
                                                    ).Include("~/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));


 @Styles.Render("~/content/assets")
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugin")
```

This works fine on dev, but when I deplot my application it looses links to few resources.

For example fowlloing links to ,Simple-Line-Icons.woff and ttf does not work as it is looking inside contents virtual folder and the fonts are some where else.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';
    src:url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot');
    src:url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.svg#Simple-Line-Icons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I could use absolute links to the resources in Css , but thinking if there is a better way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue.

We work with gulp and so have a srcdirectory and a dist directory.

while in src the font lay in both situations the fonts are in src --> fonts or dist --> fonts, the uses less/css are differently:

src-->less-->app--> style.less and
dist-->css-->style.min.css

We now write our styles in less, so that it will result in working CSS. 
The confusing part is, that the less file has an error and can´t find the font-file because of the different hierarchy. But once you understood why, this works just fine for us. Maybe you can handle it the same way, otherwhise I assume absolute path would be the way to go.